# Locking a file to be inaccessible by users

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating an application that stores passwords in different text files known as Password Banks. I want to make it so that the text files are locked away from the user and make it so that only the script can view and edit the files. The user should not be able to edit or view the file. This is a windows-only application if that makes things any different.

I've looked all over the internet and have not been able to find any way to do this. I mean, is it even possible to do so? Maybe it would be possible to use a lock function that locks the file and unlocks the file when something needs to be written to it? Here is the context in which I want to lock away the file and be editable through the script.

```py
    try:
        if bankToSend_password == (banks[bankToSend]):
            open(create_bank_file, 'a').write(#whateverneeds to be written)
            #ideally this is where the file should be locked away but still 
            #be accessible by the script.
```

I expect the file to somewhat be hidden on the user's computer and if the user manages to find it an error message should pop up to let the user know the file is inaccessible. That's my approach but other things might work.

Comment: Isn't this the goal of encryption? Not to make files inaccessible, but rather unreadable without the key.

Comment: That is quite true, however, I was still wondering if there is any other way to make this possible OTHER than encryption.

Comment: What's stopping the user from opening your script and copy-pasting the part that unlocks and reads the file?

Comment: @Azerox I truly believe the answer you are going to receive will be about the basis of encryption. Unless of course you password-protect the file somehow (think like pdfs...), but then you are prone to bruteforce methods.

Comment: Based on what @Kevin said, in order to decrypt an encrypted file you need a key which would need to be stored in ANOTHER text file. So, what's stopping the user from using that key in the text file?